# How do I iterate through a vector of maps

Tags: c++, iterator, c++14, stdvector, stdmap

I code for fun. I created a vector of maps to see what I can do with containers. When I iterate through the vector, only **Alfred** and **Angela** show up. How do I display **all** the names? Is it even possible? Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    //create a map
    std::map<std::string, unsigned int> mySuperCoolMap;
    mySuperCoolMap["Edward"] = 39;
    mySuperCoolMap["Daniel"] = 35;
    mySuperCoolMap["Carlos"] = 67;
    mySuperCoolMap["Bobby"]  =  8;
    mySuperCoolMap["Alfred"] = 23;

    std::cout << "\n\n";

    //Ranged based for loop to display the names and age
    for (auto itr : mySuperCoolMap)
    {
        std::cout << itr.first << " is: " << itr.second << " years old.\n";
    }

    //create another map
    std::map<std::string, unsigned int> myOtherSuperCoolMap;
    myOtherSuperCoolMap["Espana"]  =  395;
    myOtherSuperCoolMap["Dominic"] = 1000;
    myOtherSuperCoolMap["Chalas"]  =  167;
    myOtherSuperCoolMap["Brian"]   =  238;
    myOtherSuperCoolMap["Angela"]  = 2300;

    //Display the names and age
    for (auto itr : myOtherSuperCoolMap)
    {
        std::cout << itr.first << " is: " << itr.second << " years old.\n";
    }

    //create a vector of maps
    std::vector<std::map<std::string, unsigned int>> myVectorOfMaps;

    myVectorOfMaps.push_back(mySuperCoolMap);
    myVectorOfMaps.push_back(myOtherSuperCoolMap);

    std::cout << "\n\n";

    //Display the values in the vector
    for (auto itr : myVectorOfMaps)
    {
        std::cout << itr.begin()->first << " is: " << itr.begin()->second << " years old.\n";
    }

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps a nested loop? So first loop over the vector then inside that loop over the maps.

Comment: (side-note:) best to avoid `conio.h` altogether and if you need to hold the terminal open under windows, simply use `getchar()` which is part of the standard C library.

Comment: Naming: `for (auto itr : mySuperCoolMap)`: `itr`is not an iterator, but a value (a pair in your case), `p` is so a better name than `itr`. (In C++17, you might even do `for (const auto& [name, age] : mySuperCoolMap)`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use nested loops. Using a debugger and printing `itr` can possibly give this intuition to you if you are learning new concepts.

```
//Display the values in the vector
for (const auto &vec : myVectorOfMaps)
{
    for (const auto &p : vec)
    {
        std::cout << p.first << " is: " << p.second << " years old.\n";
    }
}
```

[**Demo**](http://www.ideone.com/Ex1NX9)

You are asking to print only first element that is why you get first element only. Note that this is a bug because you are accessing first element of map without ensuring whether map is non-empty or not.

---

<sup>Note that `<conio.h>` is not a standard header and may not be available for standard platforms</sup>

Comment: Your loops should iterate using references to avoid making copies of all the objects involved: `for (auto &vecitr : myVectorOfMaps) { for (auto &mapitr : vecitr) { ... }`

Comment: Thank you so much. I got it to work with your suggestion @GyaptiJain.

Comment: Thank you @RemyLebeau. I always forget about those references.

Answer (score 3):

The object you obtain in the for loop is an `std::map`. So you need to use another for loop to go through all the entries in each map.